# Extract all tables and h4 from html

Tags: python, notepad++

I have a html file from which I want to extract all tables and h4 elements. That is I want to take only tables and h4 from the file and use it somewhere else. I am using Notepad++ and looking for some pythonscript to do so.

```
<html>
// header
<body>
  <div>
  <h4></h4>
  <h4></h4>
  <table>
    // some rows with cells here
    </table>
  // maybe some content here
  <table>
    // a form and other stuff
  </table>
  // probably some more text
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you done, so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the module [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4).

You could accomplish what you want by doing:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    code = file("file.html")
    html = code.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    htag = soup.findall('h4')
    tabletag = soup.findall('table')
    for h in htag:
        print h.text
    for table in tabletag:
        print table.text
```

Answer (score 2):

Since BeautifulSoup already has been mentioned i just want to hint at the tools of the standard library.

You may use the [builtin html parser](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#examples) or  an [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (see [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)).

Sometimes these tools are sufficient. It depends on the task.

BTW: Notepad++ supports regular expressions.`<h4.*?/h4>` or `<table.*?/table>` allows you to select those blocks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The established go-to library for parsing and editing HTML with Python is called [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).